# HP ProLiant DL360 G4 Install on an existing OS

Tags: hp-proliant, ubuntu-16.04

I received a few weeks ago a HP Proliant DL360 G4.
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8iBt.jpg).

I tried to install ubuntu server on it, just to click around and see what I can do with it, nevertheless the install fails somehow.

There is an installed Win server 2003R2 on it, but I do not think it should be problem (or maybe I'm wrong?).

I made a bootable usb key, plugged into the rear port (the front usb accepts only the keyboard, cannot boot from it) and give it a go.
After the std boot process the ubuntu shows up, and the usb key blinks as well, but after a few moments, it switches to console (I know this is ok yet) then goes dark, and the monitor also displays a `Non optimum mode`  error msg. 
After this everything just hangs, no usb blinks nothing happens at all.

I excluded the hw issue possibility as the winserver boots up just fine.

So far I only worked with desktop computers, worked with servers only remotely. :-)

Any idea what did I wrong, or how to continue from this point?

Comment: check on hp website and stick to a linux release that was ready for that server, or use hp proliant install cd, they can customize the os to include the correct driver, but as its a old server dont expect to run a newer linux os easilly on it.

Comment: Ubuntu does that crap on a wide variety of hardware. It's a very common problem that mostly affects only Ubuntu and its derivatives. See for instance [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/470492/75668) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your monitor or try **Alt** & **Ctrl** & **+**/**-**  keys on the additional number pad to change screen resolution.

In addition, read  [Boot Parameters](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/ch05s03.html) and [Ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions?action=fullsearch&value=linkto%3A%22BootOptions%22&context=180).
And add kernel parameters `vga=normal fb=false` in boot grub menu.